# Compiling html templates to complete website

Tags: html

I'm used to using ASP.NET and visual studio to develop websites. I'm trying to develop a plain .html website in a similar matter. What I mean is use master pages etc so there is code reuse and maybe deploy these template files to a group of .html files.

For example

head.html

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
```

header.html

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->
```

footer.html

```
<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 
        #include(head.html)
</script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    #include(header.html)

    #include_body()

    #include(footer.html)

</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
<div data-role="content">   
    <p>Page content goes here.</p>      
</div><!-- /content -->
```

and combine all of these into a single output file....

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Page content goes here.</p>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Does anything like this exist? I'm not familiar with ruby or anything...

Comment: if you're a beginner and don't want to spend money I would recommend looking at wordpress with php for low cost and wide documentation. If you're familiar with ant and want to compile your site before deploy then look at htmlBoilerplate build scripts. Finally if you feel bad ass and have ressources to run your own dedicated server, then yeah go for ruby.

Comment: @mika well the reason I want to use plain html is the only server side processing will be done to just combine the files. I just want to save development time and not combine files

Comment: Look into SSI (server-side includes). You can embed HTML files inside each other.

Comment: Then I would recommend looking into HtmlBoilerplate ant build scripts, it's not exactly what you want but it should take you there. https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script But there is probably something more specific to your need out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server-side includes (SSI) may meet your needs. With some basic server requirements met, you can do, for example:

```
<!--#include virtual="includes/my_file.html" -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a little PHP to do this using includes.

Header, footer etc could be created as new .php files where you place everything you want to be displayed in that section in.

Then, in say your index.php file you do something like

```
<?php
    include ('header.php');
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
<?php
    include ('footer.php');
?>
```

Everything inside the header and footer PHP files will be included.